# Should project.lock.json file be checked into source control? (ASP.NET Core 1.0)

Tags: asp.net

Using ASP.NET Core 1.0, is it best practice to check in the **project.lock.json** file into source control?

Comment: See also http://blog.brunomlopes.com/2015/07/should-i-put-projectlockjson-in-source.html

Comment: Recommended files to ignore for .Net Core are in [VisualStudio .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore#L45)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Short answer**: No, project.lock.file should not be checked into source control - you should configure the version control system to ignore it (i.e. add it to .gitignore if you're using git).

**Long answer**: The project.lock.json contains a snapshot of project's whole dependency tree - not just packages listed in "dependencies" sections, but also all resolved dependencies of those dependencies, and so on. But it is not like ruby's [Gemfile.lock](http://bundler.io/v1.3/rationale.html#checking-your-code-into-version-control). Unlike Gemfile.lock, project.lock.json doesn't tell `dotnet restore` which exact versions of packages should be restored - it simply gets overwritten. As such, it should be treated like a cache file and never be checked into source control.

If you check it into version control, then most probably on other machine:

- `dotnet` will think that all packages are restored, but in fact some packages might be missing and the build will fail, without hinting the developer to run `dotnet restore`
- project.lock.json will be overwritten during `dotnet restore` and in most cases will be different than the version stored in source control. So it will be modified in almost every commit
- project.lock.json will cause conflicts during merge

Comment: on the other hand a package could have been updated, breaking your code. and you can't reproduce the issue. commiting the lockfile in git will make you realize dependencies are updated and the working of your project/app can not be guaranteed unless tested.

Comment: To [Enable repeatable package restore](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Enable-repeatable-package-restore-using-lock-file#solution---summary) "The lock file should be checked into the source repository".

Comment: This answer is not correct as aluded to by @Peter above. You should commit the lock file into source control as it contains the dependecy tree that the developer used to build against locally. Therefore the same tree should be used in CI and in deployed artifacts.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you do want to commit your project.lock.json in git sometimes.

### Checking your project json

For the exact reasons that, it shows you the dependencies you have used. Say:

1. Me as a developer works on an application, i hate every time updating packages so i add a package dependency to nuget package X = 1.*
2. I restore package i get version 1.2.4
3. The package maker just made a very stupid mistake, he broke something while just trying to make a fix and release 1.2.5
4. Person 2 checks out (or even worse release build kicks in).
5. Person 2 restores and gets version 1.2.5
6. Person 2 runs your application and find the application is broken.
7. Person 2 starts debugging and thinks there must be a bug in the software.

At this step 7 Person 2 could have seen in git that his lock file was changed and a newer version of a library has been downloaded, Which has not been tested by any of the other developers!

#### Downsides

Downsides of checking in this file is you might get allot of merge conflicts on continues updates of packages.

### Alternative solution

Use only hard version dependencies (this is quite hard though for nuget). And only manually update to newer version once in a while.

#### Downsides

- This doesn't work if you build a library for other people to use, since you pin them to a certain version of your dependencies.
- Dependencies of dependencies still get resolved automatically so if you don't specify them yourself you can't guarantee there version on `dotnet restore`

### Conclusion

If you want to avoid 'Works on my machine' quotes and the hell of constantly manually updating to newer version: Checking the project.lock.json.

And also build a CI/Release build check to test if this file wasn't changed compared to git, before you release (If your software is very critical)!

If this is not a problem and also automatically updating (to a potentially broken package) is not a big problem, you might not want to commit your project.lock.json.

Comment: So you are saying do not check in the lock file so that you can better be situated for someone releasing a broken version a package a developer is referencing in his/her project and because you hate updating packages every time? And the first scenario, broken release package, happens how often compared to merge conflicts?

Comment: @BrianOgden Dotnet packages are generally very stable. And i wouldn't suggest to check in lockfiles unless your application is mission critical and is  not always properly tested after release/publish. Especially when using alot of branches the lockfile will probably result in alot of merge conflicts so its not adviseable.

Comment: I am confused, your answer says to check  project.lock.json files into source control, correct?

Comment: @BrianOgden Yes my answers, gives reasosn why you would want to put your project.lock.json. This does not mean that for your project these reasons  are valid or have enough weight, to do so. its a tradeof: easy merging, vs. knowing when packages update. Alternative would be to always use hard defined dependencies (no ranges) and update ones in a while. this way you wouldn't need to commit lockfile either.

Comment: @BrianOgden I changed my comment a bit to bring some nuance.  just wanted to show another side of this question, i don't want to start a flame-wars on what is best practice. I want you to see what the advantages are, so you can wisely choose which way to go for your project.

Comment: Downside is that this file contains absolute paths that are branch-specific. So you can't have it in source control unless you somehow fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, `packages.lock.json` should be committed/checked-in.**

At least as of 2023, the answers stating "No" are wrong:

1. The official NuGet wiki page ["Enable repeatable package restore using lock file"](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Enable-repeatable-package-restore-using-lock-file#solution---summary) explicitly states

> The lock file should be checked into the source repository.

2. The Microsoft Learn article [Cache NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/caching-nuget?view=azure-devops) states

> Make sure you check your packages.lock.json file into your source code.

(*sic*, probably meant to say source *control*)

3. The Microsoft DevBlogs article ["Enable repeatable package restores using a lock file" (2018)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/enable-repeatable-package-restores-using-a-lock-file/) states

> - You must **commit/check-in** this file in the source code repository so that it is always available for restore.
> - The lock file is a tool (NuGet) generated file and should never be manually edited.
> - Lock file should not be put inside a package. It does not have any significance within a package and will never be used by NuGet.

Thus, there are at least three different official sources/documentation references that directly contradict *No* and state *Yes* instead.

---

#### Reasoning

The lock file can be used for different scenarios including:

- Ensuring repeatable builds regarding the dependency resolution - see the [NuGet Wiki](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Enable-repeatable-package-restore-using-lock-file#solution---summary).
- Caching restored NuGet dependencies in CI pipeline caches - see [Cache NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/caching-nuget?view=azure-devops).

Both just make sense if the full dependency tree is shared accross builds/developers/machines.

The `packages.lock.json` file will also just be created if this feature is explicitly enabled:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If the file is available, one can use `dotnet restore --locked-mode` to restore the dependency tree that is persisted in the lock file. This makes most sense on build servers (for either repeatable restores, caching, or both) - where the like file will just be available if it is committed.

---

#### Further Thoughts

Another common way to use locked mode is to have something like the following in your `csproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreLockedMode Condition="'$(ContinuousIntegrationBuild)' == 'true'">true</RestoreLockedMode>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And then starting a build like this:

```bash
dotnet build -c Release /p:ContinuousIntegrationBuild=true
```

In cases where deterministic builds should be used, it also makes sense to lock the dependency tree and thus enable locked mode exactly when a deterministic build is created. See [Producing Packages with Source Link: Deterministic Builds](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/producing-packages-with-source-link/#deterministic-builds) for more information on the `ContinuousIntegrationBuild` property.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is just a **lock file**, really you should never check it in when a lock file exists (except if the program who locked it wants to check it into source control, in that case, exclude your lock file!).